# Regular Expression to include only the words branches and trunk?

Tags: regex, jenkins

I am trying to filter the svn url by the regular expression in jenkins. I want to include only branches and trunk in the regular expression, can any one suggest me for the filter?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what directory structure you are using. I am asuming you are using the following structure:

```
-projectA
   -trunk
   -tags
   -branches
```

I also assume that the url is otherwise valid

```
(branches|trunk)\/([^/]+)
```

In case of a branch, this will give you the branch name. In case of trunk, the first sub directory/file of the path

simply use `branches|trunk` in case you don't want the name

Comment: Thanks Somesh. It list only branches followed by project name. If i want to list both branches and trunk except tags, what should i do? can u suggest the expression.